# Brand new Rails app 6.0.2.1 using Ruby 2.7.0 causes Traceback (most recent call last): bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootsnap

this appears to be happening for me on a brand new rails app 6.0.2.1 running Ruby 2.7.0

```
$ be rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.2.1 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:37: warning: Using the last argument as keyword parameters is deprecated; maybe ** should be added to the call
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.2.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:110: warning: The called method `initialize' is defined here
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
bin/rails: Bootsnap::LoadPathCache::FallbackScan
    74: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    73: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    72: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    71: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    70: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    69: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    68: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    67: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    66: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    65: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    64: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    63: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    62: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    61: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    60: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    59: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    58: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    57: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    56: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    55: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    54: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    53: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    52: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    51: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    50: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    49: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    48: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    47: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    46: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    45: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    44: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    43: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    42: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    41: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    40: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    38: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    36: from /Users/jason/Work/Verso/verso-commerce/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    35: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    34: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    33: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    32: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    31: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    30: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    29: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    28: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    27: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    26: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    25: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    24: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    23: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    22: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    21: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:129:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    20: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    19: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
    18: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    17: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    16: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    15: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    14: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:22:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    13: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:64:in `initialize_i18n'
    12: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:64:in `new'
    11: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:62:in `initialize'
    10: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:15:in `silence_warnings'
     9: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:28:in `with_warnings'
     8: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:15:in `block in silence_warnings'
     7: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:63:in `block in initialize'
     6: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
     5: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
     4: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
     1: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': cannot load such file -- listen (LoadError)
    74: from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
    73: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    72: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    71: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    70: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    69: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    68: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    67: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    66: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    65: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
    64: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    63: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
    62: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
    61: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
    60: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
    59: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `perform'
    58: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:138:in `tap'
    57: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:147:in `block in perform'
    56: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
    55: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
    54: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
    53: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
    52: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
    51: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
    50: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
    49: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
    48: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/rack-2.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
    47: from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    46: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:48:in `require_relative'
    45: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `require'
    44: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:291:in `load_dependency'
    43: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:325:in `block in require'
    42: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
    41: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
    40: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    39: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
    38: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
    37: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require'
    36: from /Users/jason/Work/Verso/verso-commerce/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
    35: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application.rb:363:in `initialize!'
    34: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
    33: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
    32: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
    31: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    30: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
    29: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
    28: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    27: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    26: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    25: from /Users/jason/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
    24: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
    23: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
    22: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
    21: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/railties-6.0.2.1/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:129:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    20: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `run_load_hooks'
    19: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:51:in `each'
    18: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:52:in `block in run_load_hooks'
    17: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:67:in `execute_hook'
    16: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:62:in `with_execution_control'
    15: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:69:in `block in execute_hook'
    14: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:22:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    13: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:64:in `initialize_i18n'
    12: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/i18n_railtie.rb:64:in `new'
    11: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:62:in `initialize'
    10: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:15:in `silence_warnings'
     9: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:28:in `with_warnings'
     8: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/kernel/reporting.rb:15:in `block in silence_warnings'
     7: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.2.1/lib/active_support/evented_file_update_checker.rb:63:in `block in initialize'
     6: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.2.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:23:in `require'
     5: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:26:in `require'
     4: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:40:in `rescue in require'
     3: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
     2: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:89:in `register'
     1: from /Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/Users/jason/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.0/gems/bootsnap-1.4.5/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require': Could not load the 'listen' gem. Add `gem 'listen'` to the development group of your Gemfile (LoadError)
```